# File upload dialog box not displaying onclick first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Once user click on **Non Transparent** part of Image, we are displaying file upload dialog box.... we have 2 images which are overlapped each other as below :--

**Issue** :

[image]

In the above 2 images, wherever i click on Non-Trans part , than file upload dialog box is displaying.... But if we click on **Overlapped** part, than its not displaying , but if we click on Overlapped part for **second time** , than its displaying **file upload dialog box** , but it should display when we click first time....

https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/EMQVqK

```js
var target;

let jsonData = {
  "path" : " newyear collage\/",
  "info" : {
    "author" : "",
    "keywords" : "",
    "file" : "newyear collage",
    "date" : "sRGB",
    "title" : "",
    "description" : "Normal",
    "generator" : "Export Kit v1.2.8"
  },
  "name" : "newyear collage",
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 0,
      "height" : 612,
      "layers" : [
        {
          "x" : 0,
          "color" : "0xFFFFFF",
          "height" : 612,
          "y" : 0,
          "width" : 612,
          "shapeType" : "rectangle",
          "type" : "shape",
          "name" : "bg_rectangle"
        },
        {
          "x" : 160,
          "height" : 296,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 296,
              "src" : "ax0HVTs.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 429,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_image_1"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 188,
              "y" : 122,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse1"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 291,
          "width" : 429,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 25,
          "height" : 324,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 324,
              "src" : "hEM2kEP.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 471,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_image_2"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 209,
              "y" : 136,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse_2"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 22,
          "width" : 471,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_2"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 0,
      "width" : 612,
      "type" : "group",
      "name" : "newyearcollage08"
    }
  ]
};


$(document).ready(function() {

    // upload image onclick

    $('.container').click(function(e) {

        var res = e.target;
        target = res.id;
        console.log(target);
        if (e.target.getContext) {
  // click only inside Non Transparent part
            var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);
            }
        }

    });

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

     function json(data)

        {
            var width = 0;
            var height = 0;

            let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

            let layer1 = data.layers;
            width = layer1[0].width;
            height = layer1[0].height;
            let counter = 0;
            let table = [];

            for (let {
                    src,
                    x,
                    y
                } of arr) {

                $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');

                var mask = $(".container").mask({
                    maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                    onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

                        img.css({
                            "position": "absolute",
                            "left": x + "px",
                            "top": y + "px"
                        });

                    },
                    id: counter
                });
                table.push(mask);
                fileup.onchange = function() {

                    let mask2 = table[target];
                    mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                    document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";
                };
                counter++;
            }

        }

json(jsonData);
}); // end of document ready

// jq plugin 

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }

        container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
            if (evt.target.getContext) {
                var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;

                $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
                container.selected(evt);
                prevX = evt.clientX;
                prevY = evt.clientY;
                var img = new Image();
                evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 10, 10);
                evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything');

            }
        };

        container.getImagePosition = function() {
            return {
                x: settings.x,
                y: settings.y,
                scale: settings.scale
            };
        };

        container.onDragOver = function(evt) {

            if (evt.target.getContext) {
                var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
                if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                    if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
                        var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
                        var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
                        if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
                            return; // position has not changed
                        settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
                        settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
                        prevX = evt.clientX;
                        prevY = evt.clientY;
                        container.updateStyle();
                    }
                } else {
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                //context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                };

                img = new Image();
                img.src = settings.imageUrl;
                img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                img.onload = function() {
                    settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                    settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                    context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                    initImage = false;
                };
            }, 20);
        };

        // change the draggable image
        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            console.log("load");
            if (img)
                img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle();
        };

        // change the masked Image
        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            if (div)
                div.remove();
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event)
            div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {

                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.temp {}

.container {
 background: gold;
  position: relative;
 
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden; 
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div class="container">

</div>
```

Note : I need Dynamic solution, so that it should work for every template like : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/YgjEKj & Overlapped parts : https://prnt.sc/mztuoa

**Edit**

Below code is responsibe for that issue, if i remove the below, then another problem is user will click on Transparent part of image & file upload dialog box will open as in [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T6rZb88ASOK5ad764_WyT2Umvijfx1vv/view)

```
var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);
            }
```

Comment: it displays for the first time I click on my end tho...

Comment: @ĐàoMinhHạt can you please refresh the page and try once....

Comment: both works for the codepen and snippet versions..

Comment: Instead of using one single background you can use 2 svgs for the two images and then a container can be used with one svg on it and the other overlapping it, that container can be used for the file upload dialog box.

Comment: i'm using Chrome  72.0.3626.121 on osx btw

Comment: @ĐàoMinhHạt please make sure you click on overlapped part.....

Comment: @Code_Ninja so you are telling i need to use 3 svgs , two for images & one for container ? i have lot of templates like this : some have 6, 8 , 9 images..... so i need to user same number of svgs as images ?

Comment: no use only 2, with some simple div as the container, the container is at the lowest z-index, so that transparent space can be used as a button and wherever the images are overlapped, button is not reachable.

Comment: Convert your images png to svg. It will be work

Comment: @AmanullahAman Sorry,  i have thousands of templates like this which contains 2, 3, 4, 8 , 9 images like https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/YgjEKj

Comment: @vickeycolors the thing that it is not possible to know which image you clicked with such layout. The transparent part of the image - it is still the same image to the browser, you can't click through it. Fix with z-index here - will be broken in different place.

Comment: @extempl but you already know that i am using pixel concept and not displaying `file upload dialog box` if user click on transparent part.....

Comment: also is it possible to get solution dynamically for all the templates as here : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/YgjEKj  [ overlapped parts : https://prnt.sc/mztuoa ] using z-index ?

Comment: @vickeycolors check my recent answer. I believe it should do the trick.

Comment: @vickeycolors Could you clarify the one thing here - do you need to know on which image click happened? Or you just need to know that the click has happened on a white part of `any` image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190282/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-extempl).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One more solution with keeping layout as it is now, is to check not `e.target` (i.e. element that was clicked), but all applicable (all which's bounding box is applicable for click position) canvases:

```
$('.container').click(function(e) {
  // filtering out non-canvas clicks
  if (e.target.tagName !== 'CANVAS') return;

  // getting absolute points relative to container
  const absX = e.offsetX + e.target.parentNode.offsetLeft + e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
  const absY = e.offsetY + e.target.parentNode.offsetTop + e.currentTarget.offsetTop;

  const $canvasList = $(this).find('canvas');
  // moving all canvas parents on the same z-index
  $canvasList.parent().css({zIndex: 0});

    $canvasList.filter(function() { // filtering only applicable canvases
        const bbox = this.getBoundingClientRect();
        const canvasTop = bbox.top + window.scrollY;
        const canvasLeft = bbox.left + window.scrollX;
        return (
            absX >= canvasLeft && absX <= canvasLeft + bbox.width &&
            absY >= canvasTop && absY <= canvasTop + bbox.height)
    }).each(function () { // checking white in a click position
    const x = absX - this.parentNode.offsetLeft - e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
    const y = absY - this.parentNode.offsetTop - e.currentTarget.offsetTop;
    const pixel = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
    if (pixel[3] === 255) {
      $(this).parent().css({zIndex: 2})
      target = this.id;
      console.log(target);
      setTimeout(() => {
        $('#fileup').click();
      }, 20);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: hi, sorry i didt tested properly before, there is small issue in your code, please check  the https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/rRZXWd , we cant able to upload images for bottom images, if we use same code in our computer & run in browser, than its working fine..... because in codepen there is less space , or if we use inspect element in our browser, than it dont work fine, but if we remove inspect element, than it work fine.....

Comment: @vickeycolors posted correct version there. Sorry not able to look at your other problems due to lack of time.

Answer (score 4):

That happens when you click on the first figure and then on the second (overlapped part), then the pixel is not `white` but `transparent`, that's why you do not see the file manager.

What I suggest here is use single image/canvas and in addition to checking color pixel under the cursor also check the position of the click (minus position of the image). In this case, you'll be able to create any logic you want.

Comment: Sorry,  i have thousands of templates like this which contains 2, 3, 4, 8 , 9 images like https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/YgjEKj , its very difficult to convert all those templates images to single image everytime....

Answer (score 4):

What is happening right now:

When you click on the overlapped part for the first time, event handler is triggered with canvas with `id:1` (because that is later in DOM), and the click is outside the container.

After first click, `container.enable` function is called, which assigns a z-index: 2 to canvas `id:0`.

Next time when you click the same part, canvas `id:0` click handler is invoked as it has the higher z-index.

So the fix is to assign z-index initially.

---

Just saw that in your case there may be 100s of images - in that case managing z-index might get tricky. The core issue is that Canvas is a rectangle element - so it captures clicks outside the container as well.

You could instead attach event handler to the document, and use document.elementsFromPoint() to get elements at particular event location and check individually whether there is one that lies within the container.

Answer (score 3):

You have not specified a `z-index` to the images while loading. So, when clicking the overlapped part, the second image gets the `z-index: 2` and that's when it becomes clickable to open the file upload.

The second time you click the 'overlapped' part, you're actually clicking the second image and not the empty area of the first image.

Adjust your `z-index` accordingly and try it out. Cheers !

Comment: If i fix the z-index, then it may work for this template, i have many templates like https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/YgjEKj , will fixing z-index will give solution dynamically ?

Answer (score 3):

Here I'm just doing prepand instead of append and I removed z-index. I think this works fine absolutely.

```
 div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
 container.prepend(div);
```

```js
var target;

let jsonData = {
  "path" : " newyear collage\/",
  "info" : {
    "author" : "",
    "keywords" : "",
    "file" : "newyear collage",
    "date" : "sRGB",
    "title" : "",
    "description" : "Normal",
    "generator" : "Export Kit v1.2.8"
  },
  "name" : "newyear collage",
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 0,
      "height" : 612,
      "layers" : [
        {
          "x" : 0,
          "color" : "0xFFFFFF",
          "height" : 612,
          "y" : 0,
          "width" : 612,
          "shapeType" : "rectangle",
          "type" : "shape",
          "name" : "bg_rectangle"
        },
        {
          "x" : 160,
          "height" : 296,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 296,
              "src" : "ax0HVTs.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 429,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_image_1"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 188,
              "y" : 122,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse1"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 291,
          "width" : 429,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 25,
          "height" : 324,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 324,
              "src" : "hEM2kEP.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 471,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_image_2"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 209,
              "y" : 136,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse_2"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 22,
          "width" : 471,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_2"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 0,
      "width" : 612,
      "type" : "group",
      "name" : "newyearcollage08"
    }
  ]
};


$(document).ready(function() {

    // upload image onclick

    $('.container').click(function(e) {

        var res = e.target;
        target = res.id;
        console.log(target);
        if (e.target.getContext) {
  // click only inside Non Transparent part
            var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);
            }
        }

    });

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

     function json(data)

        {
            var width = 0;
            var height = 0;

            let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

            let layer1 = data.layers;
            width = layer1[0].width;
            height = layer1[0].height;
            let counter = 0;
            let table = [];

            for (let {
                    src,
                    x,
                    y
                } of arr) {

                $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');

                var mask = $(".container").mask({
                    maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                    onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

                        img.css({
                            "position": "absolute",
                            "left": x + "px",
                            "top": y + "px"
                        });

                    },
                    id: counter
                });
                table.push(mask);
                fileup.onchange = function() {

                    let mask2 = table[target];
                    mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                    document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";
                };
                counter++;
            }

        }

json(jsonData);
}); // end of document ready

// jq plugin 

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
               
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                
            });
        }

        container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
            if (evt.target.getContext) {
                var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;

                $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
                container.selected(evt);
                prevX = evt.clientX;
                prevY = evt.clientY;
                var img = new Image();
                evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 10, 10);
                evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything');

            }
        };

        container.getImagePosition = function() {
            return {
                x: settings.x,
                y: settings.y,
                scale: settings.scale
            };
        };

        container.onDragOver = function(evt) {

            if (evt.target.getContext) {
                var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
                if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                    if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
                        var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
                        var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
                        if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
                            return; // position has not changed
                        settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
                        settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
                        prevX = evt.clientX;
                        prevY = evt.clientY;
                        container.updateStyle();
                    }
                } else {
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                //context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                };

                img = new Image();
                img.src = settings.imageUrl;
                img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                img.onload = function() {
                    settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                    settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                    context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                    initImage = false;
                };
            }, 20);
        };

        // change the draggable image
        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            console.log("load");
            if (img)
                img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle();
        };

        // change the masked Image
        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            if (div)
                div.remove();
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event)
            div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {

                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.prepend(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.temp {}

.container {
 background: gold;
  position: relative;
 
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden; 
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for snippet, now when i click on first time : `file upload dialogue box` is opening, but i cant able to drag the uploaded image.....

Comment: well the question is regarding click event. I answered that way. I'll check the drag issue.

Comment: Actually dragging was working before , please check code snippet in question.....

Comment: could you recheck whether its working or not in your question snippet. I saw its not working.

Comment: please check video here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Km9RgoKCWaSZcQM0dLT36lKy44JeY0ha/view

Comment: @vickeycolors check now. Your drag is working along with click event.

Comment: please click on overlapped part - > upload image , then click on 1st image - > upload image, again click on `overlapped part` - > not allowing to upload image onclick first time....

Comment: @vickeycolors could you check now. I removed z-index. Is there any other scenario?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190279/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-ram-ui).

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution here is to use different "whites" for different images. 
Just change white of the first image a bit, like `rgb(255, 255, 254)` and differentiate them by colors. Such difference shouldn't be noticeable by the user.
This could be automated by canvas:

Let's add config for 14 (from chat discussion) images (this could be generated, but for current case no need in it):

```
const colors = [
  "254, 255, 255",
  "255, 254, 255",
  "255, 255, 254",
  "254, 255, 254",
  "254, 254, 255",
  "255, 254, 254",
  "254, 254, 254",
  "253, 254, 254",
  "254, 253, 254",
  "254, 254, 253",
  "253, 254, 253",
  "253, 253, 254",
  "254, 253, 253",
  "253, 253, 253",
  "253, 255, 253"
]
```

Let's add one more method to the plugin:

```
      onImageLoad: function (context, width, height, id) {
        const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
        for (let i = 0; i < imageData.data.length; i += 4) {
          // is this pixel the old rgb?
          if (imageData.data[i] === 255 &&
            imageData.data[i + 1] === 255 &&
            imageData.data[i + 2] === 255
          ) {
            const color = colors[parseInt(id)].split(', ');
            // change to your new rgb
            imageData.data[i] = parseInt(color[0]);
            imageData.data[i + 1] = parseInt(color[1]);
            imageData.data[i + 2] = parseInt(color[2]);
          }
        }
        context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
      },
```

and call it here:

```
      image.onload = function() {
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
        if (settings.onImageLoad)
          settings.onImageLoad(context, image.width, image.height, canvas.id);
        div.css({
          "width": image.width,
          "height": image.height
        });
      };
```

So now we can determine id of the clicked image by color:

```
$('.container').click(function(e) {

  var res = e.target;
  target = res.id;
  console.log(target);
  if (e.target.getContext) {
    var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
    console.log(pixel);
    const color = `${pixel[0]}, ${pixel[1]}, ${pixel[2]}`;
    const id = colors.indexOf(color);
    console.log(id, 'clicked')
    if (pixel[3] === 255) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        $('#fileup').click();
      }, 20);
    }
  }

});
```

The only thing left to do for you here is to draw all images in a single shared canvas, so there won't be overlappings left and you should be ok.

UPD: working example: https://codepen.io/extempl/pen/moGPQL

Comment: So for first image, do i need to use `rgb(255, 255, 254)` , for 2nd image : `rgb(255, 255, 253)` , for third : `rgb(255, 255, 252)` so on ? i have 8 images in some templates : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/YgjEKj ,  overlapped parts : https://prnt.sc/mztuoa